# Why delete method gives me wrong path? with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have simple delete link:

`= link_to "Delete", messages_path(message.id), :method => :delete`

Gives me error:  `No route matches [DELETE] "/messages.316"`

How to fix this?

I have ruby 1.9.3p0 Rails 3.1.1

My routes.rb

```
  resources :messages do
    collection do
      get :outbox
    end
  end
```

when i change this to `message_path` i recieve `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` -> full_trace: https://gist.github.com/1967988
-> all files: https://gist.github.com/1967994

```
   outbox_messages GET    /messages/outbox(.:format)          {:action=>"outbox", :controller=>"messages"}
           messages GET    /messages(.:format)                 {:action=>"index", :controller=>"messages"}
                    POST   /messages(.:format)                 {:action=>"create", :controller=>"messages"}
        new_message GET    /messages/new(.:format)             {:action=>"new", :controller=>"messages"}
       edit_message GET    /messages/:id/edit(.:format)        {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"messages"}
            message GET    /messages/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"show", :controller=>"messages"}
                    PUT    /messages/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"update", :controller=>"messages"}
                    DELETE /messages/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"messages"}
```

**EDIT:**
Releated with [How to destroy polymorphic model? Method destroy missing argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549876/how-to-destroy-polymorphic-record)

Comment: What does your routes.rb file have?

Comment: What is the output of `rake routes`? What does your `Message` model look like?

Comment: ```DELETE /messages/:id(.:format) {:action=>"destroy", controller=>"messages"}``` im using this gem: https://github.com/LTe/acts-as-messageable/blob/master/lib/acts-as-messageable/message.rb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to say `message_path` (singular) since it is the path for a *single* message:

```
link_to "Delete", message_path(message.id), :method => :delete
```

Comment: @regedarek Okay… was there a problem with my answer? Having your controller code isn't necessary.

Comment: Yes when i use code from your answer, i recieve this error: ```wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)``` full trace: https://gist.github.com/1968069

Comment: @regedarek Please see my comment on your question and provide the additional information I asked for there.

Comment: Hmm, ```undefined method `model_name' for Fixnum:Class```

Comment: @regedarek Sorry, you need to pass `message` not `message.id`. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: i check whaut is under @message in destroy action: ```#<ActsAsMessageable::Message:0x00000003f21608>```

Comment: @regedarek Okay… so what happened when you tried my updated answer?

Comment: ```undefined method `acts_as_messageable_message_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000040cd858>:0x000000040d1de0>```  FULL TRACE: https://gist.github.com/1968180

Comment: Okay, so, I just realized the error you're getting is in your controller. My original code *is* working, but you have a completely different problem in your controller. You should create another question for that. The routing/`link_to` isn't the problem anymore. (I think I know what the issue is there, so feel free to link to the new question here).

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong URL helper. Just pass the `message` variable as the second argument for `link_to`.

Example:

```
= link_to "Delete", message, :method => :delete
```

Comment: i get this: ```undefined method `acts_as_messageable_message_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000036c3920>:0x000000036cc520>``` full trace: https://gist.github.com/1967994#file_error+full+trace

Answer (score 0):

You want `message_path(message)` not messages_path. messages_path returns the index.