# How to destroy polymorphic model? Method destroy missing argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, destroy

Im using this gem to add private messages to my application.

https://github.com/LTe/acts-as-messageable/blob/master/lib/acts-as-messageable/message.rb

I`m trying to add remove link to message.

So in my controller i have destroy action:

```
  def destroy
    @message = current_user.messages.with_id(params[:id])
    if @message.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "All ok"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Fail"
    end
  end
```

And in my view i have link: `= link_to "Delete", message_path(message.id), :method => :delete`

But when im trying to click link i receive: `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`

This is related with this question: [Why delete method gives me wrong path? with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549439/why-delete-method-gives-me-wrong-path-with/9549510)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're getting *all* messages, so `@message` is really multiple messages. You probably want to do:

```
@message = Message.find(params[:id])
```

But this may be different for the gem. The [gem's documentation](https://github.com/LTe/acts-as-messageable/blob/master/README.md) has a section on deleting at the bottom of the [readme](https://github.com/LTe/acts-as-messageable/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: I change this to ```@message = current_user.messages.with_id(params[:id]).first```

Comment: @regedarek Yup, that will likely have the same effect since `current_user.messages.with_id(params[:id]).size` is probably `1`.